# javascript augmented prototype and chain

Tags: javascript, prototype, chain, function-object

I don't understand why if I add a property or function to a prototype of an existing function object that property or function is not recognized as belonging to the object.

Example:

```
var a = function() {};
a.prototype.c = function() {/* code */};
a.c();           //c is not a function
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is because you added it to the prototype of that function, not to itself.
But if you make a new object from it you will have `c`

```
var a = function() {};
a.prototype.c = function() {/* code */};

var b = new a;
b.c(); // works as expected
```

Comment: Yes...I kown that..but according to javascript fields resolution, if an object can't find the function or the property in the object itself it look up in the prototype...isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that's called inheritance. in order to benefit from inheritance, you should create a new object using new(). Now in your example, we are creating a function and augmenting its prototype. Why? Because we want to use it as a constructor class; meaning that it will be used to create new objects. Douglas Crockford is an expert on this topic, i highly recommend you check [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg) if you wanna know more